# name not found globally code error

Tags: python

```
def choose():
  file = pickAFile()
  pic = makePicture(file)
  return pic

def negative(pic):
  for p in getPixels(pic):
    setRed(p, 255 - getRed(p))
    setGreen(p, 255 - getGreen(p))
    setBlue(p, 255 - getBlue(p))
  explore(pic)

def main():
  choose()
  negative(pic)
```

I get this error:

> The error was:pic
>   Name not found globally.
>   A local or global name could not be found. You need to define the function or variable before you try to use it in any way.
>   Please check line 15 of C:\Users\nh_2109\Desktop\s

Help?:D

Comment: I took a look at your code and listed a fix, but I think you might be misunderstanding above and beyond what you asked. If you're still confused at the end of my post, let me know and I'll revise with a much better explanation.

Comment: What are you running the code with that produces error messages like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a misunderstand in variable definition.

At the end of `choose()`, you `return pic` but you don't assign the variable to anything. Note, the variable `pic` in `choose()` and the `pic` in `negative()` are entirely different variables that exist only while the function is running.

In order to fix this, you need to make the following edit inside `main()`:

```
def main():
  picture = choose() #The "return pic" in "choose()" assigns picture = pic.
  negative(picture) #You are passing "picture" into negative(), where inside the "negative()", pic = picture.
```

Do you understand the concepts of Function Parameters vs Arguments? If not, I will add to this and explain it to you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `pic` in your main method.

```
def main():
   pic = choose()
   negative(pic)
```

is probably what you want since `choose()` returns an instance of a `Pic` class.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says you never define pic globally.
You return pic from choose but you never assign it to anything.
Change the code to

```
def main():
    pic = choose()
    negative(pic)
```