# Definition variable not found

Tags: python

I'm rather new to Python and trying to create several different definitions that run each other and refer to different variables in each. Could someone help me as to why this code doesn't work like this and what I need to change to make it work?

From what I thought, it defined what the variable `testing` was in the `test1` definition and then it would pull that in the `test2` and run in the `run_this`...

```
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def test1():
...     testing = 1
... 
>>> def test2():
...     print testing
... 
>>> def run_this():
...     test1()
...     test2()
... 
>>> run_this()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in run_this
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in test2
NameError: global name 'testing' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [name not found globally code error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568703/name-not-found-globally-code-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `testing` variable is scoped to `test1()`. In Python, variables defined inside functions are local to that function - no other functions or operations can access them.

When `test2()` tries to print from some variable called `testing`, it first checks for variables defined inside `test2()`. If it doesn't find a match, Python looks in the rest of the script for a match - since it's a scripting language, you could have defined `testing` outside both functions, in which case you'd get the behavior you're expecting. Since there isn't anything in the global scope, Python raises a `NameError`, letting you know that it can't find anything named `testing` inside `test2()`.

Comment: So if I made this script into a module, would I then be able to call it like `def test2(): print test1.testing`?

Comment: @double_j - Not really. Take a look at this question and its top accepted answer for another good explanation of Python's scoping rules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules

Comment: @double_j - `test1()` is still a function, and `test2()` still would not be able to access variables inside it. If you had defined `testing` outside the function, it would be accessible, but global variables should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: I get it now, I read that post you mentioned and it makes a lot more sense! I just need to re-write my whole script... :/ I totally thought definitions worked a little differently, but that's why I'm still learning

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be easily fixed by changing testing to a global variable:

```
testing = 7

def test1():
    gobal testing
    testing = 5

def test2():
    print(testing)

if __name__ = "__main__":
    test1()
    test2()
```

Note, that it is only required in routines doing *write access* to declare the variable as global, because otherwise a local variable with same name would be assigned and lost at procedure exit.